# Морфология слов-сокращений "соцзаказ" и "соцработник"

Tags: морфология, недопустимая-метка

Какой морфемой является `соц` в словах-сокращениях `соцзаказ` и `соцработник`?
Префиксом или частью составного корня?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

На сегодня в лингвистике нет единого мнения относительно морфемного статуса  подобных словоэлементов. В школе это корень. В вузе -переходное явление от корня к префиксу - префиксоид(аффиксоид).

В.В.Лопатин называет аффиксоидом «компонент сложного или сложносокращенного слова, повторяющийся в составе ряда слов и приближающийся по своей словообразовательной функции (способность образовывать новые слова с тем же компонентом) к аффиксу – суффиксу или префиксу » (Лопатин 1997). Он приводит значительно расширенный перечень примеров префиксоидов: «само- (самообслуживание, самодисциплина), полу- (полукруг, полупроводник), лже- (лженаука, лжеученый) <…>, видео- (видеофильм, видеопленка), орг- (оргработа, орготдел)» (Лопатин 1997). Также отнесены к аффиксоидам «связанные компоненты сложных слов, не выступающие в качестве корневых в словах иной структуры, напр. <…> префиксоиды <…> аэро- (аэровокзал, аэросев), псевдо- (псевдоискусство, псевдоготический), еже- (ежедневный, ежегодный)» (Лопатин 1997).

В словаре префиксоидов есть следующие элементы:  агропром... ‘относящийся к сельскому хозяйству на промышленной основе ʿ (агропромхолдинг ), бизнес... ‘относящийся к бизнесу, связанный с ним ' ( бизнес-план ),  инвест...‘ инвестиционный '(инвестбанк  ),   эконом... ‘ экономический ' ( экономполитика ). Видимо, и "соц" можно сюда отнести: "относящийся к социальной сфере"-соцработник, соцзащита, соцобслуживание, соцпакет.

Что не префикс - это точно, но вот корень или префиксоид - это смотрите, как Вам это подают в учебном заведении.

Comment: +много. )) Даже и добавить нечего. )) А что за словарь префиксоидов? Никогда не слышал.

Comment: @людмила, спасибо за столь развёрнутый ответ! А можно ссылку на словарь префиксоидов? Поисковый запрос по этой фразе выдаёт несколько ресурсов и 1 научную статью, но словаря нет.

Comment: Простите за долгое молчание, было некогда зайти на сайт. Ссылку на словарь  дать не могу, онлайн его нет, сама воспользовалась книгой "Словарные материалы - 80", она у меня в печатном виде, там ссылка на словарь Левашова( чем и пользуются все в научных статьях на сайтах). Там же ссылки на Лопатина.

Answer (score 2):

В ваших примерах "соц" -это часть корня - "социальный".

Answer (score 2):

Из словаря на Грамоте.ру

СОЦ... **Первая часть сложных слов**. 1. Вносит зн. сл.: социалистический. Соцреализм, соцсоревнование, соцобязательство. 2. Вносит зн. сл.: социальный. Соцобеспечение, соцбытсектор.

АГРО... [от греч. agrós - поле]. **Первая часть сложных слов**. 1. Обозначает отнесённость чего-л. к землепользованию; аграрный. Агробизнес, агрогород и т.д.

**А где же префиксоиды, надо поискать.**

[ПРЕФИКСОИДЫ КАК СЛОЖИВШАЯСЯ СИСТЕМА СОВРЕМЕННОГО РУССКОГО СЛОВООБРАЗОВАНИЯ](http://www.science-education.ru/120-16059)

Итак, префиксоид - понятие строго научное, что видно из следующего текста " В статусе префиксоида тот или иной структурный элемент сложного слова **утверждается не сразу.** Как правило, диахронический путь  префиксоида включает следующие этапы: представленность в составе композитов, отдельные выделения компонентов, но уже с указанием их  семантики, признание элемента в статусе префиксоида, семантика которого сначала  трактуется вариативно. Таким образом, каждый структурный элемент, приобретший статус префиксоидности, имеет **свою  историю становления,** в результате которого в общей системе языка сформировалась подсистема семантически значимых компонентов слов гибридного    характера,  демонстрирующих сложившиеся системные связи разного типа".

Поэтому принадлежность "соцработника" к сложносокращенным словам или словам с префиксоидом **нужно  доказывать**, а не полагаться на частное мнение конкретных учебных заведений.

Comment: Вера, Вы снова "умствуете", а человеку нужно выполнить задание - в соответствии с требованиями своего преподавателя, иначе он получит "2", ведь каждый преподаватель вуза, например,требует свои лекции, знание своей позиции. Термин префиксоид сейчас используют в науке повсеместно, но границы между корнем и префиксоидом размыты, иногда просто говорят "первая часть сложных слов", а какая это морфема - корень или префиксоид- назвать не решаются. Иногда такие части (усечённые прилагательные) называют ещё аналитиком. Так что пусть человек  разбирает так, как в его уч.  заведении

Comment: Людмила, ну это же шутка, ирония такая. Я просто хотела высказаться о таких упражнениях в целом, по-моему, префиксоиды это и есть псевдонаука, судя по приведенной мною цитате.  А человеку нужно не только выполнить задание и получить 5, но и относиться критически к изучаемому материалу. Кстати, в вопросе ничего не говорится о префиксоидах, может быть, они вообще не пользуются такой терминологией.

Comment: Вполне возможно, потому я и прошу всегда, чтобы пояснили, где учится автор вопроса. Если в школе - ответ один, если в колледже - другой, в вузе-третий, и то не всегда одинаковый. И студенткам, когда за помощью обращаются, говорю: "Посмотри сначала в свою лекцию".